# Programmatically change Drupal username on creation

Tags: drupal-7, str-replace

My Drupal site enables Single-Sign-On with an external service by sharing username and password data. If the user is new, the username and password is used to create a new account on the external service.
The problem is the external service is not happy with spaces in the username.

I wrote the following code into a Drupal module to remove spaces from the username when an account is being created:

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
    if( $account->is_new ){
        $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $account->name);
        drupal_set_message("CHANGING {$account->name} TO {$name}");
        $account->name = $name;
    }
}
```

When the account is created, I see the default confirmation message such as the following:

> Created a new user account for test_test1. No e-mail has been sent.

That confirms my string replacement is taking effect but when I view the user account it still contains spaces.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You should ask this on the Drupal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used hook_user_presave() to make it work. Refer this: [user hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/7). By the time, `hook_user_insert()` is called the user is already created.

I used `hook_user_presave()` because it is invoked when a user account is about to be created or updated. I used `$account->is_new` to perform the task on new accounts only. Then I edited `$edit` instead of `$account` directly because [user_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) takes 2nd argument(an array) to save in `$account`.

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if( isset($account->is_new) && $account->is_new === TRUE ) {
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $edit['name']);
    // Also consider trimming the length and to lowercase your username.
    drupal_set_message("CHANGING {$edit['name']} TO {$name}");
    $edit['name'] = $name;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I tried that hook and it failed to give me the desired effect

Comment: well i confirmed that this hook works. updating the answer with screenshot.

Comment: and did you used `edit` array instead of `account` object?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was assigning to the account object instead of the edit array. Thanks alot for all you assistance.